# macでスリープ状態でもコマンドを実行し続ける方法

Tags: python, macos

とあるSNSのbotを制作中なのですが、macの画面を閉じると実行を止めてしまうので、
nohupというコマンドをつけて実行してみたのですが、それをつけてもスリープ状態？画面を閉じると止まってしまいます。
どのように書けばコマンドを実行し続けられますか？
ちなみにpythonの実行ファイルです

情弱ですみません...

Comment: ちょっとモノが無いので確実ではないですが、画面を閉じてもスリープしないようにOSの設定変えるのが早いんじゃないでしょうか？環境設定にそんな設定ありませんでしたか？あと、tagにunixが入ってるのはtagを間違えただけ？？？

Comment: 上の方も書かれていますが、InsomniaXのようなアプリを利用して、画面を閉じてもスリープさせない、というアプローチはいかがでしょうか。
http://sitemiru.com/2014/02/12/mac-insomnia-x/

Comment: 暫定的にos-xタグに変更しました。

Answer (score 2):

タイトルに書かれていることに忠実に回答すると、スリープ状態でコマンドを実行するのは**不可能**です。スリープ状態では、メインメモリの状態は保持されていますがCPUやハードディスクは動いていないので、プログラムは実行できません。文字通り寝ている状態です。

起きている時しかプログラムを実行できないので、バックグラウンドでプログラムを実行したい場合はスリープ状態にしないようにするか、何らかの方法でスリープ状態を解除する必要があります。

ちなみに、MacにはPowerNapという機能があり、スリープ状態でも一時的に起動してプログラムをバックグラウンドで実行する機能がありますが、これはOSのサービス専用なので残念ながら任意のプログラムを実行するようなことはできません。

Answer (score 0):

Pythonではないですが、RubyOnRailsで、あるサイトをScrapingするバッチをWEBアプリとして作成し、数分おきにcronで開始URLをたたくシステムを作って、自分のmac book proでテストしていましたが、PCを閉じて１日置いて、次の日開いてみると、閉じている間も処理をしていました。

処理自体は、スレッド化していて、WEBサーバー自体もシェルでバックエンドで起動しています。

おそらく、ターミナルなどで単純にPythonをフロントプロセスとして起動すると閉じるとスリープしてしまいそうですが、バックエンドとしてデーモンのように起動すれば実行し続けるのではないでしょうか？

Pythonでどのような実装なのかわかりませんが、DjangoなどのFWを使っているのであれば、おそらくバックエンド起動のオプションがあるはずです。

追記：

すいません、こちらわたしの勘違いで、MACを閉じた場合は完全にスリープ状態になるので、デーモン化しても処理は止まってしまいますね。

省エネモード（一定時間放置されてスクリーンセーバーが表示されている場合）には、処理が継続するのは確認しました。

なので、画面を閉じずに放置している分には、少なくともデーモンプロセスは動くとおもいます。

ちなみに、Pythonで３秒ごとに現在時刻をファイルに書き込む処理を書いて、ターミナルから実行してみましたが、スリープ状態になっても画面を開けると処理は勝手に再開しますが、このことと上記の画面をあけたまま放置する運用で、普段使うmacであればわりと継続的に処理は続けられると思うのですが、これでは解決にはならないんですかね？